# Question(s) regarding understanding of denseness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I think I have some problem understanding the definition and the implication of denseness in metric spaces.

Kolmogorov and Fomin in "Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis" state the following (some parts omitted):

The space of bounded sequences ($l_\infty$ but called $M^\infty$ in the book) is not separable. In fact, let us consider all possible sequences consisting of zeros and ones. They form a set with cardinal number that of continuum. The distance between two such distinct points is 1. We surround each of these points with a sphere of radius $\frac 1 2$. These spheres do not intersect. If some set is everywhere dense in the space under consideration, then each of the indicated spheres should contain at least one point of this set and consequently it cannot be denumarable.

Here, I am wondering how we can conclude that the full space is not separable if we only consider the subset of sequences consisting of zeros and ones? Is there a more detailed explanation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They construct an uncountable collection of balls that don't intersect. This implies that the space is not separable : indeed, if there was a countable dense subset $\mathcal{P}$, then each ball should countain at least one element of $\mathcal{P}$, but this contradicts countability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subset $A$ is dense in a metric space $X$ when every point $x\in X$ is in the closure of $A$. Thus every open ball $B_r(x)$ contains a point of $A$ distinct from $x$. So, the centers of disjoint open balls cannot be dense in $X$.

In the given example, the centers of the balls are the $0$-$1$ sequences, which are uncountable. Given any dense set $A$, however, each of these balls must contain at least one point of $A$, all distinct from each other. This means that any dense set $A$ must be uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is a  countbale dense set $(x_n)$. Then each of the spheres mentioned above contains at least one of the points $x_n$. Pick one such for each sphere and map the sphere to the the integer $n$ you obtained. You get a one-to-one map from an uncountable set to the set of positive integers. This contradiction proves that $\ell^{\infty}$ is not separable.